# c# Compilation on runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on a C# Web application which in fact the user is going to built through this application a new web application with his requirements. It is going to be like an Object relational  mapping online platform. For this i will need a runtime compiler. I found some examples for winforms projects but nothing for web application runtime compilation. Any help or examples from where can i start?

Comment: It is exactly the same. Try harder.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference when compiling from a winform app or from a webform app ( a part from some trust issue you can have in a web application ). Just use [CodeDom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2k85ax6.aspx) features of the .NET framework.